# Unable to access Keychain...sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am developing a Swift app that allows users to store user information (password, authToken etc) in the iOS keychain. I am using Matthew Palmers Locksmith library. I am able to save, delete and sometime retrieve information.

When a user first logs in to the app I validate and store their email in app defaults and authToken and password in keychain. I then use:

```
let email = appDelegate.defaults.valueForKey("email")!
let dictionary = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("\(email)")
```

to get the details and perform API requests with this information. 90% of the time this works as expected but often, usually after the app is inactive for a period of time (I don't know what causes this as it changes) I can no longer access the dictionary item.

I am calling the above code every time I need to make an API call and I know that I cannot load the data because I am doing:

```
if let dictionary = dictionary {
  // DO SOMETHING HERE
}else{
  print("Can't get the data")
}
```

Is calling Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount every time I need to make a network call (through Alamofire) a good idea? Anyone know why I would not be able to access the keychain sometimes?

Some posts on SO say it's because of the Swift Compiler Level but it is already set to -Onone

This happens on both device and simulator running on iPhone6 9+